# Adding an image in every cell of a table

Tags: tables, graphics

I am trying to insert an image in every row (apart from the first row of each column) but every time I try to insert an image in the last cell of each row it does not work, please see below.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{Morphological Table}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|}  
        \hline
        \hline

    \textbf{} & \textbf{Idea 1} &  \textbf{Idea 2} &  \textbf{Idea 3} &  \textbf{Idea 4}  \\ \hline \hline

    (eg) Hoist Motor & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg}  & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} \\  \hline 

    1 & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} \\ \hline


\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If the content of the final cell of each row is replaced with simple text the table acts as normal (eg below) ; which is confusing me on why only the final cell affects the outcome:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{Morphological Table}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|}  
        \hline
        \hline

        \textbf{} & \textbf{Idea 1} &  \textbf{Idea 2} &  \textbf{Idea 3} &  \textbf{Idea 4}  \\ \hline \hline

        (eg) Hoist Motor & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg}  & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & 1 \\  \hline 

        1 & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & DC Motor \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{saxion-logo.jpg} & 1 \\ \hline


    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Thank you in advance for any input

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  (i fixed the beginning of the code.  very simple -- just highlight with your mouse the block of code that you want to mark, then click on the `{ }` icon at the top of the question box.)

Comment: thank you for editing it, and for the appropriate instructions - much appreciated!

Comment: If you have `\centering` in the last cell of a row, end the row with `\tabularnewline` instead of ``\\``

Comment: thank you so much @egreg - that solved the issue perfectly, very much appreciated!

Comment: @egreg Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`\centering` changes the meaning of `\\`; if you have it in the last column of a table, change the row ending `\\` into `\tabularnewline`.